# how to pick and pass two parameters while running a bat file?

Tags: xml, excel, batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm doing automation to perform application migration. Created a .bat file with the below code

cd c:\bin\

apputility.bat c:\backup\migration.xml

Now I want to run the same .bat script to migrate multiple applications by picking up two strings from an excel file. passing those two strings to the migration.xml file. so whenever The bat script runs it needs to run the same migration.xml by passing those to strings. The excel file will be like this

app1    app1

app2    app2

app3    app3

app4    app4

whenever the .bat runs,it should run passing "app1" "app1" parameters into migration.xml. If there are  4 rows it needs to run 4 times.

Thanks in advance and hoping for the quick assistance.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? XML files don't take parameters.

Comment: While taking back up an application all the info will be saved in .xml file like application name and folder name which it will be saved into after migration(two parameters which I want to pass). Now whenever I create a new application I want to take back up with the same bat file. Instead of using .bat and xml for  every application, I want to use same bat and xml file for multiple applications

Comment: Open a command prompt window, enter `call /?` and hit key Return to execute this command. Among other stuff displayed in help of internal command __call__ you can also read about `%1 %2 %3` which are for referencing argument (parameter) 1, 2, 3, ... of the batch file.